# Make jar run in 32bit jre

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

How can I specify that in order to run a certain java application that I created you need to have 32 bit JRE installed on your system? Further how can I specify that the java application is to use the 32 bit JRE and not the 64 bit JRE if they are both installed?

Background:

I have created an application that uses a 3rd party 32 bit only library. The application can not run in a 64 bit JRE.

I am going to be distributing this application to a lot of computers in my company, so I need to be able to in code or in the export process, specify the required JRE.

I am using eclipse, Kepler to develop and build the java application.

Comment: If it's possible, obtain the source of your library and build for 64-bit machines. :) Just throwing that out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of java is always compile once and run everywhere, regardless of OS, cpu architecture etc, so you might be heading the wrong direction here.

But nevertheless here are some system properties you might / not find helpful. I've listed the property key and value I have when I check it (I run Oracle JDK on Win7 64)

- java.vm.name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
- sun.arch.data.model: 64
- sun.cpu.isalist: amd64

To use any of those just do

```
String vmname = System.getProperty("java.vm.name");
```

Comment: For Java bytecode it makes no difference if the JRE is 32-bit, 64-bit or something else, but Reid mentions in his question that he is using a 32-bit native library, so his program only works on a 32-bit JVM; a 64-bit JVM cannot load 32-bit native libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly in Java, since you're in a running JVM at that point. My solution was to write a dos batch script to set the JAVA_HOME and add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` at the front of the PATH. For example, I have `sethome.bat` which contains

```
@echo off
set "JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6"
set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
```

Then I use

```
call "%SERVICE_HOME%\sethome"
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -version
echo If this does not look correct press CTRL-C to cancel otherwise
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generally make sure what program runs your jar. I can pass the jar to `acroread`, or `zip` or whatever, and you can't do anything about it.

So, I'd just try to load the library, and do a proper error/exception handling. Who knows? Maybe your client has meanwhile replaced that library with a 64bit version, without you knowing about it? SO, this: loading, and if it won't aborting with a graceful eror message is the only sensible thing.